# How to get contentview inside UIScrollView to fill parent with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

So I have a working UIScrollView with a content view that can scroll horizontally no problems there. I've followed all online resources I've could find and everything related to scrolling works... My problem is that the content that is put inside the contentview does not fill to the UIScrollViews bottom. It's like the scrollbar takes up the bottom 5-10 pixels making it impossible for the content to stretch there.

At the attached example image it can be seen that the text doesn't align along whole the bar, all items are added in same fashion, the only different is those inside the small scroll area has the UIScrollView as parent. The frustrating thing is this was not an issue if I set the frame and content area instead of using autolayout constraints.

[image: Example of issue]

Everything is in code (except the out most parent which has a fixed height constraint of 50 and margin of 0 to left and right)

Constraint for Scrollview and content view:

```
    //
    // scroll constraint
    //
    barScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // left constraint
    let leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: barScrollView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: menuBtn, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(leftSideConstraint)

    // top constraint
    let topSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: barScrollView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(topSideConstraint)

    // bottom constraint
    let botSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: barScrollView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(botSideConstraint)

    // right side constraint
    let rightSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: barScrollView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: collapseBtn, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(rightSideConstraint)


    //
    // scroll content constraint
    //
    barScrollContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // left constraint
    let contentLeftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: barScrollContentView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: barScrollView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    barScrollView.addConstraint(contentLeftSideConstraint)

    // top constraint
    let contentTopSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: barScrollContentView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: barScrollView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    barScrollView.addConstraint(contentTopSideConstraint)

    // bottom constraint
    let contentBotSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: barScrollContentView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: barScrollView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    barScrollView.addConstraint(contentBotSideConstraint)

    // right side constraint
    let contentRightSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: barScrollContentView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: barScrollView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    barScrollView.addConstraint(contentRightSideConstraint)
```

And all items inside is added like following:

```
/**
 Add constraints to an item used in the bar

 - parameters:
   - newElement: The new element that is added
   - leftElement: The element to the left of the new element
   - parent: The parent view the constraint is added to
   - width: The size of the new element
   - isFirstItem: Boolean indicating if this item is the furtest item to the left side
 in the current container
 */
func addConstraintToItem(newElement: UIView, leftElement: UIView, parent: UIView, width: CGFloat, isFirstItem: Bool) {
    newElement.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Width constraint
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newElement, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: width)
    parent.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    // Height constraint
    //let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newElement, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.frame.height)
    //parent.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    // left constraint
    var leftSideConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint

    if isFirstItem {
        leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newElement, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: leftElement, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    } else {
        leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newElement, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: leftElement, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    }
    parent.addConstraint(leftSideConstraint)

    // top constraint
    let topSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newElement, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    parent.addConstraint(topSideConstraint)

    // bot constraint
    let botSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newElement, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parent, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    parent.addConstraint(botSideConstraint)
}
```

Comment: Can you just try hiding the scroll indicator to check if it is causing the label to compress?  self.tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false. Also, can you print the frame of the barScrollContentView, elementView and the bottom label? to check which of those is not getting the expected height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding two more constraint to `barScrollContentView` : `Center Y (Vertically in container) and fixed width`. This may solve your problem i think.

Comment: Fixed width is not a possibility as I have a horizontal scrollview, fixed height made the scroll freeze, I'll try to center again ( have tryed it before but had other issues at that time)

Comment: You should give fixed width. you can increase it when needed by increasing constant of that constraint. When you add new view increase width constraint's constant as added view's size

Comment: Yes but that is not really a dynamic approach is it... I wanted to try to use autolayout to adjust the size. Anyway the centerY did it :D, no need for anything else, that was simply the missing peace. Thanks a lot.